# installing plugin in eclipse-cpp-helios-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop

Can someone tell me how to install a map reduce (hadoop) plugin in eclipse-cpp-helios-SR2-linux ? Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the hadoop plug-in site if you find a site which provide hadoop plug-in  than

There are two way to do it.

1:As you read over the net copy the plug-in and paste it into Eclipse plug-in folder and restart the eclipse. This is not the best way to install plug-in.

2:  The proper way to install plug-in in eclipse is following  :
Go to Help menu in Eclipse main window  press Install new software.
 Here in tab work with just put the address of website from where you want to install the plug-in.

Write any name for plug-in than look in the text box.  it will provide you proper name of the plug-in and "next " tab  at the bottom will be activated.

Press the next tab,It will install your plug-in .
At the end of installation just restart the eclipse to take the new setting effect.

Comment: as for the first approach to install hadoop this approach will work in eclipse which got java your eclipse don't have java tool chain thats why hadoop plug-in is not working. You try this approach with eclipse which has java it will work

Comment: for second approach you need website which provide hadoop plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

hi 
you can try this approach. Use any latest version of eclipse and than install CDT in it. This will allow you to write c/c++ application.

for your hadoop just go to you hadoop installation directory,here in contrib folder you will find eclipse plug-in in this folder you will get the jar file, just copy this file in to eclipse plug-in directory and restart the eclipse.
Now check for map-reduce perspective in window->open perspective and select build configuration according to your system